# How to save a query at variables using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this SP:

```
create procedure SP_Filas
(@fact int)
as
select COUNT(C.id_art) from cat_articulo C inner join det_factura D on C.id_art =        D.id_art
inner join factura F on F.id_fact = D.id_fact
inner join cat_cliente B on B.id_cliente = F.id_cliente
where D.id_fact = @fact
```

This SP is going to throw, for example, 3.
How could I save that 3 into an int variable at C# Asp.NEt?

Comment: Well, first you should say what "it's not working" means... is there an error? What's the issue?

Comment: It doesn't save the results of the SP in my DataTable so I can't save the values of my query inot the variables D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not suggesting to use `array` to store these much amount of data. Create a custom `class` with the members you required like below and add each instance to a `IEnumarable` collection

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string id_art { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string precio { get; set; }
}


SqlConnection cnx;
String cadCnx = "Here goes my credentials"
cnx = new SqlConnection(cadCnx);

String query = "exec SP_Datos_PDF @fact";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnx);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fact", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fact;

cnx.Open();  

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= filas; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];

         var item = new MyClass();
         item.id_art = Convert.ToString("id_art");
         item.nombre = Convert.ToString("nombre");
         item.precio = Convert.ToString("precio");
         Items.Add(item);  
         i++;
    }
}
```

Still you not required a custom `Class`, then use `Tuple` instead

Comment: Your code does not answer the question "when I try to print the total_fact..." and does not help because it still includes issues mentioned by D Stanley

Comment: I have not added total_fact in MyClass model. you can add this property and do the same what you are doing in the old snippet.

Comment: Please see the answer properly before down voting

Comment: While the OP asked about total_fact and not about model, the main  problem with your code is not in total_fact. Your code does not work - see answer of D Stanley 1) cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fact", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fact; 2) item.id_art = Convert.ToString("id_art"); 3) DataRow row = dt.Rows[0]; 4) i++;

Comment: THat's something very pro for me but I've solved my problem. The SP which counts the rows at SQLServer isn't working and that's why it wasn't saving. Thanks a lot, bro.

Comment: @smirnov We are explaining what is the best practice.... so whatever code he wrote we are remolding it, and he mentioned that The logic and the code he posted was working fine for him. The question is all about how to save a query at variables using C#. So I have suggested custom class and Tuple to archive it. The snippet which I posted was the same he posted in his question.

Answer (score 2):

I realize you're probably new to C# (and maybe programming in general), but you have MANY problems to find and fix - I would suggest starting over, and build your program up one piece at a time, using the debugger (or unit tests) to validate the results as you go.  Right now it appears that you're throwing a bunch of code together (likely copied and pasted from other sources) and trying to unravel all of the problems.  That approach will result in adding patches (that will be difficult to understand later) to solve logic issues, rather then systematically building up your program piece by piece.

That said...

I see several issues:

- You are mixing the syntax of `AddWithValue` and `Add`.  Use either:

  ```
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@fact", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fact;
  ```

  or

  ```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fact", fact);
  ```
- You're not actually extracting the data from the table.  You need to use the column name indexer on the `DataRow` :

  ```
   total_fact = Convert.ToString(row["total_fact"]);
                                 ^--^
  ```
- you are always just reading the first row (`DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];`)
- you are calling `i++` twice for each item - one in the loop definition and again at the end of the loop
- Why are you extracting the values to arrays with a fixed size of 50?  Why not just keep the `DataTable`or use `List<>`?

Comment: Still not working. What I need is the the values, for example, id_art =5, 6, 7 that comes from my DB are saved ay my array id_art[] but it isn't saving a thing D:

Comment: @RalphVB see my edit.  You are probably not getting any rows results because of the bad value for `@fact`.  Do you know how to use the debugger?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections :p (Shame on me because the double i++)
And I need to save into arrays because I'm going to print all the info I'm extracting from the DB into a PDF. 
And still not saving. Let me edit my question for the new code I have :)

Comment: You should still be able to use a `List<>` or `DataTable` to iterate through and save into the PDF. If you still plan on using a fixed-index length of 50, then you should ensure that the maximum value for `filas` is 49, otherwise you will hit an index out of range exception.